# Getting printable style of a page without calling window.print()

Tags: javascript, css, jspdf, html2canvas

I need the client to save the printable version of a page as a pdf **without** the user having to open up the print dialog and choosing "Save to PDF" themselves.

I'm using jsPDF and html2canvas. I have a printable style for the page using:

```
    @media print {
        @page {
            margin: 0cm;
        ...
```

and so on.

I'm using a function like this to save the document:

```
 function savePDF(){
        html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                var img=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'A4');
                doc.addImage(img,'JPEG',0,0);
                doc.save('report.pdf');
        });
    }
```

My question is, how do I access the printable version of the div I'm selecting?

I'm wondering if there's something like:

```
$(document.body).mediaStyle('print')
```

that I could use to select the div with its printable style.

Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding jsPDF and it will only allow me to print what's being displayed to the user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The linked answer does not describe how to do this programmatically